# Bind control handles to SwiftUI Shape

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

I'm trying to bind control handles to a `Shape` using a custom wrapper view `ShapeControlsView` containing the Shape itself and Shape controls with `DragGestures` to modify the shape.

This is the desired result:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU6O5.png)

I had a working solution, which relied on `@State` properties in the ContentView itself, but this required adding more properties for each Shape so this wasn't a viable solution.

With my current attempt, the control handles are visible and the `DragGestures` get triggered, but actually dragging the handles to modify the Shape doesn't work.

Maybe someone can give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here?

**Code example:**

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Example Shape
struct Line: Shape {
    @State var startPoint: CGPoint
    @State var endPoint: CGPoint
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        path.addLine(to: endPoint)
        path = path.strokedPath(.init(lineWidth: 4))
        return path
    }
}

// Protocol to ensure Binding
protocol HasControlPoints {
    var controlPoints: Binding<[CGPoint]> { get }
}

// Set up Binding for the Line's start and end point
extension Line: HasControlPoints {
    var controlPoints: Binding<[CGPoint]> {
        Binding(get: {
            [startPoint, endPoint]
        }, set: { newValue in
            startPoint = newValue[0]
            endPoint = newValue[1]
        })
    }
}

// Custom View Wrapper for Shape and ShapeControls overlay
struct ShapeControlsView<ContentView: Shape & HasControlPoints>: View {
    var content: ContentView
    @Binding var controlPoints: [CGPoint]
    
    init(content: ContentView) {
        self.content = content
        self._controlPoints = content.controlPoints
    }
            
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Shape
            content
            
            // Shape Controls with DragGestrue
            ForEach(controlPoints.indices, id:\.self) { index in
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    .position(controlPoints[index])
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged {
                                controlPoints[index] = $0.location
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}

// Content View
struct ShapeControlsDemo: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ShapeControlsView(content: Line(
            startPoint: .init(x: 100, y: 100),
            endPoint: .init(x: 200, y: 200))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to make a minimal example... you have a lot of irrelevant code, such as your previews and styling, such as fill color. Removing these makes your question easier to answer!

Comment: @Stoic Thanks for the feedback. I edited my question and tried to simplify the code example as much as I could.